# How to send packet message for specific NIC in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm a beginner with Socket programming in c# and I wonder how to send packet data for specific NIC.

I knew there was a way to set specific network device using setsockopt in python3 like that

```
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str(str(netinterface) + '\0').encode('UTF-8')) // netinterface => 'eth1'
    except OSError :
        print("Failed set eth1")
```

there were eth0 and eth1 and I did send packet successfully to eth1.

I found a way set option to socket like this, but I dont know how to resolve NIC using this APIs.

```
        UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 15118));
        IPAddress multicateAddress = IPAddress.Parse("FF02::1");
        udpclient.JoinMulticastGroup(multicateAddress);

        Socket uSocket = udpclient.Client;

        uSocket.SetSocketOption() // <- How... to?
```

If there is tutorials or any documents, it will help me.

Please comment thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether `bind` your socket to a specific IP address of an interface on the NIC you're looking for or modify your OS routing table to send packets to a specific network through a specified interface.

`UdpClient` isn't just a socket, but anyway I don't see an issue in binding it to a specific IP. See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k227d11f(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.